# Multiple INSERT in one query using MySqlCommand

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, sqlparameter, prepared-statement

I am using the following code:

```
        string cmd = "INSERT INTO " + Tables.Lux() + " VALUES(NULL, @Position, @Mode, @Timer)";
        try
        {
            using (var MyConnection = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DataFormConnection"].ConnectionString))
            {
                using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(cmd, MyConnection))
                {
                    MyConnection.Open();
                    command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("Position", Element.Position));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("Mode", Element.Mode));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("Timer", Element.Timer));
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
```

I am using the above code to insert data from a list of Element containing 100 items. I would like to add 100 values in only one query, and I know that the SQL statement looks like:

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b) VALUES (1,2), (2,3), (3,4);
```

but I don't know how to apply that structure using the `MySqlCommand.Parameters` approach.

My goal is to pass this function `List<Element>` instead of just `Element` and create an `INSERT` statement with all the items in the list to be executed in only one query. Any help please?

Thank you.

Comment: Do the Values come from another SQL Table?

Comment: You could create a stored procedure call this once, and then in here do your insert statement, if you are inserting from another table you can use this table to generate your data that will be inserted.

Comment: The answer to your question is in your post/code. You just need to add parameters not values. Later you can replace parameter value just before calling ExecuteNonQuery() method.

Comment: @DavidBeaumont: The values are stored in a List, they are simple logs that I want to save.

Comment: @AVD: That is exactly what I would like to do, but I have no experience in this field and I can't find how to do that. All the information about multiple queries I found address the SQL statement point of view, not the application from a programmer point of view.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
string cmd = "INSERT INTO " + Tables.Lux() + " VALUES ";
int counter = 0;

foreach (Element e in list) 
{
    sql += "(NULL, @Position" + counter + ", @Mode" + counter + ", @Timer" + counter + "),";
    command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("Position" + counter, e.Position));
    command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("Mode" + counter, e.Mode));
    command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("Timer" + counter, e.Timer));
    counter++;
}

command.CommandText = sql.Substring(0, sql.Length-1); //Remove ',' at the end
```

This way you can have a variable number of parameters in your query and you only have to fire it once against the database, not n times

This is untested, just out of my head!

Comment: @Hamma  Please discuss in the comments, not by editing Posts  A and B are placeholders for your parameter names, sry I hadn't written them with the `@` in front

Comment: Ok it makes sense now. Sorry for editing, I was trying to comment but writing code looked so messy that I figured it would be so much easier to read the other way.
I will try this, thank you!

Comment: No problem, I hope it helps you

Comment: @Hamma Please mark as an answer if this post was able to help you

Comment: Yes, I tried it and it is working. I am adding 100 lines in one query right now.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

I used @xenogenesis answer to solve my problem, maybe can help someone else

```
List<EntregadorRPC.Address> addresstoinsert = eoSendAddressList.addresses;

int      batteryLvl = eoSendAddressList.batteryLevel;
DateTime dtHoraLocal;
int      size = addresstoinsert.Count;

const string insertHeader = "Insert into historicolocalizacao (Provedor, CodUsuario, Latitude, Longitude, Precisao, Logradouro, " +
                            "Complemento, Setor, Cidade, UF, Cep, DataHoraLocal, bateria) Values";

StringBuilder insertValues = new StringBuilder("");

using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand()) {

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        EntregadorRPC.Address address = addresstoinsert[i];

        dtHoraLocal = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        dtHoraLocal = dtHoraLocal.AddMilliseconds(address.dataHoraLocal).ToLocalTime();
        /*address.logradouro       = WSUtils.RemoveSpecialCharacters(address.logradouro);
        address.formattedAddress = WSUtils.RemoveSpecialCharacters(address.formattedAddress);*/

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue($"@provedor{i}",      address.provedor);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue($"@user_id{i}",       user.user_id);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue($"@latitude{i}",      address.latitude);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue($"@longitude{i}",     address.longitude);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue($"@precisao{i}",      address.precisao);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue($"@logradouro{i}",    address.logradouro);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue($"@complemento{i}",   address.complemento);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue($"@setor{i}",         address.setor);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue($"@cidade{i}",        address.cidade);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue($"@uf{i}",            address.uf);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue($"@cep{i}",           address.cep);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue($"@datahoralocal{i}", dtHoraLocal.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue($"@bateria{i}",       batteryLvl);

        insertValues.Append($"(@provedor{i}, @user_id{i}, @latitude{i}, @longitude{i}, @precisao{i}, @logradouro{i}, @complemento{i}, @setor{i}, @cidade{i}, @uf{i}, @cep{i}, @datahoralocal{i}, @bateria{i})");

        if (i < size - 1) {
            insertValues.Append(",");
        }
    }

    cmd.Connection  = conn;
    cmd.CommandText = $"{insertHeader}{insertValues}";
    await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
}
```